# Google Search Console API doesn't show "Submitted URL has crawl issues" that is a problem for a number of my URLs in Search Console

Tags: google, google-search-console, python

I use Google Search Console to track my URLs errors.
I also use Google API with google-api-python-client.

When I do this Python line :

```
errors = webmasters_service.urlcrawlerrorscounts().query(siteUrl=site_url).execute()
```

I get the following :

```
{
    "countPerTypes": [
        {
            "platform": "web",
            "category": "notFound",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "6",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "web",
            "category": "notFollowed",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "0",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "web",
            "category": "authPermissions",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "0",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "web",
            "category": "serverError",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "1",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "web",
            "category": "soft404",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "0",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "web",
            "category": "other",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "0",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "smartphoneOnly",
            "category": "notFound",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "13",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "smartphoneOnly",
            "category": "notFollowed",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "0",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "smartphoneOnly",
            "category": "authPermissions",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "0",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "smartphoneOnly",
            "category": "serverError",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "0",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "smartphoneOnly",
            "category": "soft404",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "0",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "smartphoneOnly",
            "category": "roboted",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "0",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "smartphoneOnly",
            "category": "manyToOneRedirect",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "0",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "smartphoneOnly",
            "category": "flashContent",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "0",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "platform": "smartphoneOnly",
            "category": "other",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "count": "0",
                    "timestamp": "2019-01-28T20:12:17.618Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I go to the Search Console interface, I get this screenshot for errors : 
[image: Search console interface]

Do you know why I don't find the category of **Submitted URL has crawl issue** in the Google API response ?

I want to manage these issue with my Python script.